# How can I rewrite this function recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Is there a way to use recursion to replace the for loop in this? I want it to print out the song 99 Bottles of Bear on the wall. I have been trying but I can not get it to work. Do I need to rewrite the code so that it can be rewritten recursively?

```
{
    function main() {
        input = Number(prompt("How many bottles do you have?"));

        for (let i=input; i > 0; --i){
            if (i == 1){
                console.log(i, "bottles of beer on the wall", i, "bottles of beer.");
                console.log("Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of bear on the wall");
                console.log("No more bottles of bear on the wall, no more bottles of beer.");
                i = input;
                console.log("Go the store and buy some more,", i, "bottles of beer on the wall.")
                break;

            }else {
                console.log(i, "bottles of beer on the wall", i, "bottles of beer.");
                console.log("Take one down and pass it around,",i-1, "bottles of bear on the wall");
            }
        }
}
main();
}
```

Comment: Yes, one can *always* replace a loop with recursion. Can you show us your attempt so we can see where you went wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the below way:

```js
function main(input, original) {
    if (!input) {
        input = Number(prompt('How many bottles do you have?'));
    }
  
    if(!original) {
        original = input;
    }

    if (input == 1) {
        console.log(`${input} bottles of beer on the wall ${input} bottles of beer.`);
        console.log('Take one down and pass it around, no more bottles of bear on the wall');
        console.log('No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.');
        console.log(`Go the store and buy some more ${original} bottles of beer on the wall.`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${input} bottles of beer on the wall ${input} bottles of beer.`);
        console.log(`Take one down and pass it around, ${input - 1} bottles of beer on the wall`);
    }

    if (input > 1) {
        main(input - 1, original);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: This is missing the `i = input;` that made the original an infinite loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Oops, sorry, *I* had missed the `break` statement in the original code, and thought the code was meant to generate the infinite version of the song text - it should not. But still, your version fails to print the original entered number ("*Go to the store and by some more; 99 bottles of beer on the wall*") in the last line of the output

Comment: Oh nice find. Will fix that now.

Comment: Edited, I don't know the song so I'm going off your comment here ;)